# How can I pivot a 2-column key/value table to a matrix of bits showing which combinations exist?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with two columns (a key and a value), that I want to pivot into a matrix of all the combinations of keys and values.  I need to do this in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm starting with a data like the table below, which just associates two values.  This example associates people to the software they have installed.  Let's call this table `PersonApps`.

```
Name      | App
------------------
Joe       | Excel
Joe       | Word
Megan     | Word
Megan     | Skype
Bjorn     | SSMS
Bjorn     | Excel
```

I want to turn that into this:

```
Name   | Excel   | Word   | Skype  | SSMS
------------------------------------------
Joe    | 1       | 1      | 0      | 0
Megan  | 0       | 1      | 1      | 0
Bjorn  | 1       | 0      | 0      | 1
```

I know this involves the `PIVOT` operator, and probably some dynamic SQL since I will not know before hand how many different values may be in the `Apps` column.  However, all the examples I can find for `PIVOT` are more complicated than what I need and use standard aggregate operators like `COUNT` and `SUM`, but I just need to check the existence of a combination.

The best script I can come up with is

```
 SELECT Name, Excel, Word, Skype, SSMS
 FROM PersonApps
 PIVOT (
     COUNT(Name) FOR App IN (Excel, Word, Skype SSMS)
 )
```

I know the call to `COUNT` is wrong.  How do I make that a bit for testing the existence of a combination?  Is there anything else I need to fix?

---

**EDIT:**

This code seems to be working.  Is there a better way though?

```
SELECT *
FROM @PersonApps
PIVOT (
    COUNT(App) FOR App IN (Excel, Word, SSMS, Skype) 
) as Pivoted
```

Comment: You code looks fine, but if you are looking for a way for this to be dynamic, i.e. account for new apps being added to the list, you can follow this tutorial http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/pivoting-dynamic-way

Comment: Thanks.  I got the dynamic bit down.  The syntax of `PIVOT` was just really confusing me for a while.